# SQL: How to convert these date strings into date types

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

How would I convert the varchar data below to a date data type with a SQL statement?

```
Oct 25, 2004
May 02, 2006
Nov 19, 2002
```

Comment: Have you tried anything?

Comment: @lad2025 Yes. I've tried cast and convert. There doesn't seem to be a format specifier for this format.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If 2012+, you can use Try_Convert().  This will return NULL for any conversion failures rather than throwing an error.

**Example**

```
Declare @YourTable Table ([SomeCol] varchar(50))
Insert Into @YourTable Values 
 ('Oct 25, 2004')
,('May 02, 2006')
,('Nov 19, 2002')
,('Not a Date Format')

Select * 
      ,AsDate = try_convert(date,SomeCol)
 from @YourTable
```

**Returns**

```
SomeCol             AsDate
Oct 25, 2004        2004-10-25
May 02, 2006        2006-05-02
Nov 19, 2002        2002-11-19
Not a Date Format   NULL           -- << Notice Returned NULL
```

Comment: What if default is not `EN`? Also `TRY_CONVERT` is available for SQL Server 2012 and higher.

Comment: says 'try_convert' is not a recognized built-in function name. Even though SSMS highlights it as a keyword

Comment: My server is 2012 but looks like the Database compatibility level was set to 2008, changed that and it worked

Comment: Ah, and I see convert fails because one of my rows have data that cannot be converted, where as try_convert skips any bad data